# c# `dictionary of dictionary` query

Tags: c#

could someone tell me the correct way to query this:

`dictionary of dictionary`

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Guid, AutoStopWatchAndLog>> _dicDictionaryThread
```

where what i am looking for is from any of the first level and then from any item in the second where the level is less than x

dics betlow is: `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Guid, AutoStopWatchAndLog>>`

```
var mostlikey = dics.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Value.Where(y=>y.Value.Level > x));
```

Comment: What structure do you want for the output?  The int from the upper level and the `Guid` from the lower level?  do you want to output the level itself?  Why are you calling `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: @DStanley you make a good point yeah ID and GUID would do... but i thought it would just filter the collections where they matched, so final will be 1 collection in INT level and one in GUID level.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to project to a *new* dictionary of dictionaries filtered to the desired items, you will need to project both levels of dictionaries, which would look something like:

```
var query = _dicDictionaryThread.Select(o => new {o.Key, Value = o.Value
                                                                  .Where(y=>y.Value.Level > x)
                                                                  .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value)})
                                .Where(o => o.Value.Any())
                                .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
```

If you can *easily* understand this and explain it to someone else, go for it, otherwise just use a traditional loop - you're not going to get any performance boost from Linq and it will likely take longer to decipher.

Comment: Linq makes it easier to understand, in my opinion. But isn't linq less performant? People use it because it's easier to understand, not the other way around.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet The performance difference is usually negligible.  The performance hit is from the additional overhead of iterators, filters, delegates, but it is usually small enough that it doesn't make a significant difference overall. I would not say that it it more "readable" in this case, though. A loop with proper comments would be easier to follow IMHO.

Comment: Agree to disagree ;)